# my simulator is not showing me full screen

Tags: xcode, simulator

my app works fine on iPhone, however I've included it to work on the iPad but when I run it to test it I don't get a full screen of the app. it looks likes an iPhone size app on an iPad.

[image: here is a screenshot]

making sure all my code is correct and it is. it works fine with my other app, just not on this one.

if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {

```
        var mainview:UIStoryboard
        mainview = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let VC:UIViewController = mainview.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "iPhoneStoryboard") as UIViewController
        self.window!.rootViewController = VC

    }

    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {

        var mainview:UIStoryboard
        mainview = UIStoryboard(name: "iPad", bundle: nil)

        let VC:UIViewController = mainview.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "iPadStoryboard") as UIViewController
        self.window!.rootViewController = VC

    }
```

my console:-

nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C5.1.1:2][0x7ffa32732090] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-08-07 16:34:38.294229+0300 ****[14161:330455] TIC Read Status [5:0x0]: 1:57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need support iPad natively.

### - Below Xcode 11

Set Devices to `Universal` in General tab of project settings:
[image: Xcode 10]

### - Xcode 11

Check iPad:

[image: Xcode 11]

Comment: rookie mistake xD